# Keep VkMainWindow on Bottom

Tags: c++, linux, kde-plasma, motif

I have an app, running on Linux, which is comprised of a VkMainWindow and several VkWindows.  The desired behavior is to keep the VkMainWindow always on the bottom (and hence, all the VkWindows always on top of the VkMainWindow).  The existing code works as advertised on KDE, but the customer decided it needs to run under MWM.  Running under MWM, the VkMainWindow raises above the VkWindows.  Any ideas?

VkMainWindow:

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(MyContainer const &container, ArgList args, Cardinal argc)  
       :  
            BaseWindow("My Base Window", args, argc,  
            _statusWindow(new StatusWindow(container)),  
            m_helpDialog(new MainHelpDialog),  
            m_container(container),  
            m_frame(nullptr),  
            m_form(nullptr),  
            _button1(nullptr),  
            _widget1(nullptr),  
            m_button2(nullptr),  
            m_widget2(nullptr),  
            m_button2(nullptr),  
            m_widget3(nullptr),  
            m_button3(nullptr),    
            m_button4(nullptr),  
            m_button5(nullptr),  
            m_widget4(nullptr),  
            _label1(nullptr),  
            _label2(nullptr),  
            _label3(nullptr),  
            _label4(nullptr),  
            _label5(nullptr),  
            _label6(nullptr),  
            _label7(nullptr)  
{  
   Display *mainDisplay;  
   mainDisplay = XOpenDisplay(0);  
   if (mainDisplay)  
   {  
        m_width = m_mainWindowWidth = 1280;  
        m_height = m_mainWindowHeight = 1024;  
        XCloseDisplay(mainDisplay);  
   }  

   XtVaSetValues(m_shellWidget, XmNmwmFunctions, MWM_FUNC_MOVE | MWM_FUNC_MINIMIZE, XmNx, 0, XmNy, 0, NULL);  
   m_configFile = currentWorkspace;   
}
```

VkWindows:

```
BaseWindow::BaseWindow(string const &name, ArgList args, Cardinal argc,  
       unsigned int createOptions, bool createTabStack, bool removeCornerFunctions, bool scrollable, bool workspaceConfigurable)  
       :  
            VkWindow(name.c_str(), args, argc), _mainForm(0), _mainOffset(   
                  MAIN_OFFSET), _buttonSpacing(BUTTON_SPACING), _createOptions(createOptions),  
            _createTabStack(createTabStack), _statusText(0), m_buttonBoxForm(0), m_helpForm(0),  
            m_okButton(0), m_cancelButton(0), m_applyButton(0), m_applyCb(0), m_okCb(0), m_cancelCb(0),  
            m_screenId(INVALID_SCREEN_ID), m_previousTab(0), _tabStack(0), _tabForm(0), m_initialized(false),  
            m_shellWidget(0), m_clipWindow(0), _isScrollable(scrollable), m_isValid(true), m_statusOnly(false),  
            m_validateOnOk(true), m_validateOnApply(true), m_widgetsMapped(false), m_fooLocked(false), m_isLocked(false),  
            m_currentSize(FULL), m_lastSize(0)  
{   
   Widget parent = mainWindowWidget();  
   XtSetValues(parent, args, argc);    

   m_shellWidget = parent;  
   while (m_shellWidget && !XtIsShell(m_shellWidget))  
   {  
      m_shellWidget = XtParent(m_shellWidget);    
   }  

   if (removeCornerFunctions)  
   {  
       if (m_shellWidget)  
       {
         XtVaSetValues(m_shellWidget,  
         XmNmwmFunctions, 22,  
//         MWM_FUNC_RESIZE | MWM_FUNC_MOVE | MWM_FUNC_MINIMIZE | MWM_FUNC_CLOSE,  
         NULL);  
         XtAddEventHandler(m_shellWidget, StructureNotifyMask, false, resizeCb, this);  
      }  
   }  
   ...  
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{
   ...  
   Cardinal ac;  
   Arg args[20];  
   std::string title("My Client");

   XrmOptionDescRec *optionList = NULL;  
   int numOptions = 0;  

   app = new VkApp(const_cast<char*>(title.c_str()), &argc, argv, optionList, numOptions);  
   ...  
   app->run();  
   ...  
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: "I can include salient code passages" - Better would be a [mcve].

Comment: Let me walk back that I can include code.  The code is export controlled and I want to be very cautious about that.

Comment: You are unlikely to get help without a minimal example that produces your problem. Don't post your application. Create a small example.

Comment: Added sanitized example.

Comment: I'm still not getting responses.  Is the example code insufficient?

Comment: Maybe use XRaiseWindow() on the VkWindows?

Comment: Yes.  I had thought of that.  It seems like you'd have to have a custom event loop that checked for ExposeEvents on the VkWindows and XRaiseWindow when encountered.

Comment: I believe a VkWindow is a Popup Shell by default and should exhibit the behavior we want. Under KDE and gnome it does.  Is it that we are not asking MWM "pretty please with sugar on top?"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call VkWindow:lower() in the event loop for the main window.